# error when using my own input with swagger 2 and spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm new to spring boot and trying to set up a swagger documentation for a web app I'm working on. It works quite well when my endpoints only require strings, list or other basic request bodies but whenever I use custom inputs I get this error : could not resolve reference because of could not resolve pointer does not exist in document
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIRrs.png)

I created a small project with just one end point to search more easily. Those are my swagger dependencies :

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
```

Here is the swagger config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("io.example.bss.testswagger"))
                .paths(any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaInfo())
    }
    private ApiInfo metaInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(

            "API",
            "A description",
            "0.0.1",
            "urn:tos",
            new Contact("someone", "https://www.google.com",
                    "an.email@gmail.com"),
            "",
            "",
            new ArrayList<VendorExtension>()
        )
        return apiInfo
    }
}
```

Then there is the controller :

```
@Controller
class ControllerHello {

    @PostMapping("/")
    def hello(@RequestBody Profile profile){
        return "hello $profile.name $profile.surname, I see you're $profile.age years old"
    }
}
```

And finally,the DTO :

```
@ApiModel(value = "the profile containing the name surname and age of a person")
@Document
class Profile {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "the name of the person", required = true)
    String name
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "the surname of the person", required = true)
    String surname
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "the age of the person", required = true)
    int age
}
```

In a similar post someone was advised to use `alternateTypeRules` in Docket, but I'm not sure it would work for my issue and I don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that swagger-ui was having trouble because my Profile class was written in groovy and it was taking the metaclass into account when displaying the model. 
The problem was solved by adding this line `.ignoredParameterTypes(groovy.lang.MetaClass.class)` like so :

```
@Bean
Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("io.example.bss.testswagger"))
            .paths(any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaInfo())
            .ignoredParameterTypes(groovy.lang.MetaClass.class)
}
```

This is my source: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/752